# Edit a json file with case-sensitive duplicate keys using PowerShell version 5.1

Tags: json, powershell-5.1

I need to use PowerShell to parse, edit, and the save a json file. I'm stuck using version 5 of PowerShell. I'm running into issues parsing the file, because the content contains case-sensitive duplicate key names.

When I deserialize using the built in ConvertFrom-Json it causes errors, because this converts all content to lowercase, which causes it to think there are duplicate keys. I was able to deserialize and convert back to json format using System.Text.Json; however, that requires version 7 of PowerShell.

I am able to successfully parse the json content using the following:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Web.Extensions")
            $jsonString = Get-Content -Path $file.FullName -Raw
            $serializer = New-Object System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
            $content = $serializer.DeserializeObject($jsonString)
```

That converts the content to an object of type System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[string,System.Object].

The json content that I am working with will have nested objects.

How can I convert that result back to json?